# Catalog needs to support pricing with 13 decimal points. after point

Tags: product, pricing

**Business Requirement: Our catalog needs to support pricing with 13 decimal points.**

Currently We are using magento 2.1 version community edition, but we have issues while saving the price with more than 4 decimal points in the backend and frontend.

As per our requirement, We need to save the price for the product with 13( 0.000056784325 ) decimal places after the decimal point.

Comment: This looks like a strange requirement. Just out of curiosity, if  you can tell for which product this price is applicable.

Comment: For Ms office service products  the price like this